# Проблема с парсингом даты и времени

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

С помощью BS4 парсю страницу стока для отзывов, нужно дату вытащить, а там такая строка

```
<cat-brand-ugc-date date="2022-08-08T01:20:56+03:00" source="flamp" url="//ufa.flamp.ru/firm/avto_klub_avtosalon-70000001041311670/otzyv-7810115">
<a href="//ufa.flamp.ru/firm/avto_klub_avtosalon-70000001041311670/otzyv-7810115" title="Сегодня в 3:20" class="ugc-date link link--grey t-text t-text--small">
Сегодня в 3:20
</a>
```

Люди добрые подскажите как можно вытащить дату в нормальном формате, а не сегодня в 3:20.

Остальные данные из отзыва доставал таким образом

```
'initials': item.find('a', class_='link name t-text t-text--bold').get_text(' ', strip=True)
```

Comment: а чем не подходит уже имеющееся полноценное значение `date="2022-08-08T01:20:56+03:00"`?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin вот в этом и вопрос как его вытащить? Я еще так сильно не шарю, но если до этого я опирался на класс чтобы данные доставать, то здесь его нет и я не знаю что делать

Comment: @там прикол в том что, один отзыв идет за другим и вот чтобы как то автоматизировать процесс решил доставать данные по форматам и классам

Comment: ну атрибуты можно получить методом `get`  `get('date')`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin емае как все просто, спасибо большое данные достал, теперь надо узнать как их хоть в чуть чуть человеческий вид привести из этого 2022-08-08T12:39:06+03:00 в что нибудь такое 2022-08-08 12:39:06, хотя и это не сложно через replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import bs4, datetime

text = '''
<cat-brand-ugc-date date="2022-08-08T01:20:56+03:00" source="flamp" url="//ufa.flamp.ru/firm/avto_klub_avtosalon-70000001041311670/otzyv-7810115">
<a href="//ufa.flamp.ru/firm/avto_klub_avtosalon-70000001041311670/otzyv-7810115" title="Сегодня в 3:20" class="ugc-date link link--grey t-text t-text--small">
Сегодня в 3:20
</a>
'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text)
cat = soup.find('cat-brand-ugc-date')
date = cat.get('date')  # 2022-08-08T01:20:56+03:00

d = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
d = d.strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")
print(d)  # 08-08-22 01:20:56
```